# Why isn't this javascript prompt working?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, prompt

I am trying to make images of the specific candy pop up when you type in its name but only Ghirardelli works.

```
<p id="chocolate"></p>
<img src="hershey.jpg" id="pic">
<script>
var y = prompt("What would you like to see a picture of?");
if (y == "Hershey")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Hershey";
}
if (y == "Reeses")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Reeses";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="reeses.jpg";
}
if (y == "Ghiradelli")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Ghiradelli";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="ghiradelli.jpg";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Please choose one of these three things: <ul><li>Hershey</li><li>Reeses</li><li>Ghiradelli</li></ul>";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="x.svg";
}
</script>
```

Comment: so, not even hershey works?

Comment: but it does display hershey on page load, right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you only have one `else` in the whole thing. The first two if statements are operating independently. They work, but the final `if` is not true when they are, so the logic in the `else` overwrites anything the first two `if`'s did.

Just make the rest `else if`.

```
var y = prompt("What would you like to see a picture of?");
if (y == "Hershey")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Hershey";
}
else if (y == "Reeses")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Reeses";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="reeses.jpg";
}
else if (y == "Ghiradelli")
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Ghiradelli";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="ghiradelli.jpg";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("chocolate").innerHTML="Please choose one of these three things: <ul><li>Hershey</li><li>Reeses</li><li>Ghiradelli</li></ul>";
    document.getElementById("pic").src="x.svg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use else if instead of multiple if.
2. Try using return as the last statement of each if statement.(I am not sure about this point, checking)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are not all being reached. A common solution to this problem is to clean up your code with either else if statements or using a switch statement. Also, I tried to abstract away from having to use too many document.getElementById statements

```
<p id="chocolate"></p>

<img src="hershey.jpg" id="pic">

<script>

//sets variable y to the response in the promt
var y = prompt("What would you like to see a picture of?");

//sets the chocolate paragraph variable
var chocolate = document.getElementById("chocolate");

//sets the pic image variable
var pic = document.getElementById("pic");

//checks for different cases of y, use switch statements when there are too        many if statements
switch (y) {
case "Hershey":
    chocolate.innerHTML="Hershey";
    break;
case "Reeses":
    chocolate.innerHTML="Reeses";
    pic.src="reeses.jpg";
    break;
case "Ghiradelli":
    chocolate.innerHTML="Ghiradelli";
    pic.src="ghiradelli.jpg";
    break;
default:
    chocolate.innerHTML="Please choose one of these three things: <ul>  <li>Hershey</li><li>Reeses</li><li>Ghiradelli</li></ul>";
    pic.src="x.svg";
}
```